# Having quite a bit of trouble with Baking

Tags: texture-baking, baking

I'm relatively new to Blender (3D modelling in general), and am working off of YouTube for the most part. I am trying to bake a head of hair and glasses (all in on object) so I can create a texture file for the model I am creating. The only tutorials relevant to my situation are outdated and therefore I cannot follow them, so here I am as a last resort.

This is what it looks like when I bake.
[image: This is what it looks like when I bake.]

And this is what the actual rendered image looks like (in Cycles).
[image: And this is what the actual rendered image looks like (in Cycles).]

I don't think it is an issue with unwrapping, but I have no idea. Any help would be greatly appreciated, this has given me bigger headaches than I would like to admit.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're trying to bake? Are you baking information from a high poly model onto a low poly model? Or, are you trying to just bake material information onto a set of textures just from the low poly? Also, can you show us what your UV map looks like?

Answer (score 0):

The hair looks to me like a problem with the normals, to recalculate normals select all the hair polygons on edit mode and click on Mesh -> Normals -> Recalculate Outside. Regarding to the colors, maybe you are changing the viewport color texture instead of using real material colors, for that when the object is selected check the materials. Also don't trust totally the render view, if your environment light is black and your hair is black your texture will end up being practically all black, try changing the light environment to white, its so easy, just clicking on the world icon and move up the color light environment slider to have white light environment. Maybe any of this helps or makes you dominate something new :-)